# How to get an XElement with special characters in XML tag

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement, xmlexception, xname

I have an XML document I'm trying to traverse, which is SDMX-compliant. Here's a short sample:

```
<root>
    <csf:DataSet id="J10"> 
     <kf:Series> 
       <value> 107.92
       </value> 
     </kf:Series> 
    </csf:DataSet>
</root>
```

However, when I try to do the following using Linq to Xml in C#, I get an XmlException.

```
XElement dataset = document.Element("csf:DataSet");
```

The Exception text is: 
The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

I have no control over the XML. Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Comment: Note that the ":" is not a special character in a tag. It s separator that separates the namespace prefix from the local name of the element.

Comment: Your XML is missing namespace declarations. See my full example. If you try to run it without "xmlns:crf=... " the Parse method throws an exception.

Comment: @Saunders, @m0sa: Thanks for the heads-up. The full document does have a xmlns entry, I just wasn't aware that the ns was for namespace! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var csf = XNamespace.Get("<csfNamespaceUri>");
document.Element(csf + "DataSet");
```

Note that you have to specify the uri of the csf namespace. A full example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<root xmlns:csf=""http://tempuri.org/1"" xmlns:kf=""http://tempuri.org/2"">
    <csf:DataSet id=""J10""> 
     <kf:Series> 
       <value> 107.92
       </value> 
     </kf:Series> 
    </csf:DataSet>
</root>
");

var dataSet = doc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/1") + "DataSet").Single();
```

Comment: I would have upvoted if you had used the simpler syntax - and will upvote if you edit your answer to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Hightechrider, I was not aware of this shortcut. Very nifty!

Answer (score 0):

Try using XNamespace to qualify the DataSet element you are looking to extract.

Comment: simple example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. One of the answers here helped me on my way, but not all the way, so here is my solution / clarification:

What you need to do is specify an URL for your namespace, like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com";
```

...then prepend that namespace in each `Element`:

```
var someElement = new XElement(ns + "ElementName", "Value");
```

**For this to work however, you *must include that specific URI* in the XML as follows:**

```
var rootElement = 
    new XElement(ns + "MyRootElement",
                 new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns", 
                                "http://www.example.com"));
```

Now you can add `someElement` (and others) to `rootElement`, and the namespace will be included, because it has been referenced (by the url) in the root:

```
rootElement.Add(someElement);
rootElement.Add(new XElement(ns + "OtherElement", "Other value"));
```

This will generate XML that looks something like this:

```
<ns:MyRootElement xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com">
    <ns:ElementName> (...) </ns:ElementName>
    <ns:OtherElement> (...) </ns:OtherElement>
</ns:MyRootElement>
```